# How to disable Kamon logging for tests?

Tags: sbt, kamon

Is there a way to use [Kamon](http://kamon.io) logging only in running the code, not in tests?

I'm using `kamon-log-reporter` and `kamon-scala` on Scala 2.12. My code-under-test uses the Kamon API so I want to have `kamon-core` both in Runtime and Test. However, I'm not interested in console logging in tests, and `sbt-aspectj-runner` plugin doesn't seem to launch AspectJ for `sbt test` (a separate issue).

My setup:

`/project/plugins.sbt`

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo("kamon-io", "sbt-plugins")                  
addSbtPlugin("io.kamon" % "sbt-aspectj-runner" % "1.0.1")
```

`build.sbt`

```
val kamonVer= "0.6.5"
 val kamon = "io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % kamonVer     
 val kamonLogging = "io.kamon" %% "kamon-log-reporter" % kamonVer     
val kamonAspectJ = "io.kamon" %% "kamon-scala" % kamonVer     

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( kamon, akkaHttp, typesafeConfig, akkaHttpTestkit, scalaTest)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(kamonLogging, kamonAspectJ)
```

I've tried this, but it makes logging disappear also in `sbt run`:

```
libraryDependencies in Runtime ++= Seq(kamonLogging, kamonAspectJ)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying
`addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.2")`

In https://github.com/Workday/prometheus-akka/blob/master/build.sbt, I use this to enable aspectjweaver in tests.

Comment: Thanks. I'm off that Kamon project, but maybe someone will try and tell if this works.